# Reading a binary file containing arrays in C or Mathematica

Tags: c, arrays, binary, wolfram-mathematica

I've been sent a binary file, which I need to read part of. The file format was described to me as:

> Line1: NLine
>
> Line2: xarray1,yarray1
>
> Line2: xarray2,yarray2
>
> Line2: xarray3,yarray3
>
> Line2: xarray4,yarray4
>
> Line2: xarray5,yarray5
>
> Line2: xarray6,yarray6
>
> Line6: xarray7,yarray7

where NLine is an integer (499 to be specific) and each xarray and yarray is a float-array with length NLine. I actually only really care about xarray7 and yarray7, but I'm happy to read all of them into arrays for this purpose and just not use the others. Anyway, I just need to turn the arrays into ascii format so I can do something else with them, or even just convert them into arrays that I can deal with locally and print out. I'm happy to do this in either C or Mathematica.

Unfortunately I can't provide the data itself or an example of a similar file -- the above is all I know. If anyone can provide a bit of code that would let me get into my file (or tell me how the file couldn't possibly be in this exact format or something), that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How does a binary file contain lines?

Comment: No idea. The person who sent me the file might be completely wrong. I'm just relaying the information they sent me. I don't usually deal with binary files so I don't know what the constraints are.

Comment: Well, did you open the file to look at its contents? Reading a binary file containing floats can be tricky, because of diffrent formats for floats and ints across platforms

Comment: Binary files typically don't use carriage returns for new lines. They are often made up of application specific format (or some generic binary format). We will need to know the format of the binary file - i.e. what binary values seperate the different lines/records and arrays... And possibly the format of the numbers!, Its not something we can really guess. If it was plain text as you have written in your example, then it is quite different...

Comment: I don't know how to look at the contents of the file. It's binary, so unless I can read it into something, I can't see what's in it.

Comment: I'd suggest the use of an hex editor. Or write a short program to open the file and start with reading the NLine value. When you read the correct value here, read the next and so on

Comment: looks like you have a solution, so i'll just comment mathematica is a very nice tool for sorting out unknown binary formats since you can readily try all manner of encodings and byte orderings.. see here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BinaryFiles.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just to get you going...

```
FILE* binFile = fopen("./path/filename.bin", "rb"); //open as binary 'b' for reading 'r'
char nextByte; // to store one byte in

// Loop through the whole file
while (!feof(binFile))
{
    // read one byte, with a size of 1 byte (could use sizeof(char) here), count of 1 from binFile, store in nextByte...
    fread(nextByte, 1, 1, binFile);

    // Print the byte
    printf("%02x ", nextByte);
}

// Close the file
fclose(binFile);
```

Once you do this it will print out the binary file in hex number (one byte per value). Then you can analyse the format.
Note: I did not test this code... you will need to include the relevant c libraries too...

Comment: Thanks. This didn't quite work (seg fault), but it helped me figure out the answer. It appears (after a bunch of trial and error) that the data format is one int then 10 iterations of 499 floats, and by using this code as a starting point, I was able to read the int using `fread(&nlines,sizeof(int),1,binfile)` and then everything that followed with `fread(&elem,sizeof(float),1,binfile)` where `nlines` was defined as an int and `elem` as a float.

Comment: oh yeah... you are meant to pass a pointer into the fread func that's probably the seg fault, sorry I missed that one :o